# Why Python does not recognize "kivy" module for me?

Tags: python, installation, module, pip, kivy

After I **install the "kivy" python module**, the python console and IDEs don't recognize it as a module, as if it doesn't exist.

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'`

I do the installation normally like any other. I reinstalled the module several times and looked for all possible solutions, but nothing. Also, `pip list` and `pip3 list` tells me the module is there. What should I do?

Comment: Can you post a sample code and also paste here the error you're getting?

Comment: Did you add KIVY to the environment variable, then only the module is initialised? https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/environment.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When I completely reinstalled the system the problem was solved.